# Mounting EFS in EKS cluster: example deployment fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, amazon-efs

I am currently trying to create an EFS for use within an EKS cluster. I've followed all the instructions, and everything seems to be working for the most part. However, when trying to apply the multiple_pods example deployment from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver), the pods cannot succesfully mount the file system. The PV and PVC are both bound and look good, however the pods do not start and yield the following error message:

```
  Warning  FailedMount       116s (x10 over 6m7s)   kubelet, ip-192-168-42-94.eu-central-1.compute.internal  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "efs-pv" : kubernetes.io/csi: mounter.SetupAt failed: rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not mount "fs-080b8b50:/" at "/var/lib/kubelet/pods/3f7c898d-c3de-42e7-84e5-bf3b56e691ea/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/efs-pv/mount": mount failed: exit status 1
Mounting command: mount
Mounting arguments: -t efs fs-080b8b50:/ /var/lib/kubelet/pods/3f7c898d-c3de-42e7-84e5-bf3b56e691ea/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/efs-pv/mount
Output: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sbin/mount.efs", line 1375, in <module>
    main()
  File "/sbin/mount.efs", line 1355, in main
    bootstrap_logging(config)
  File "/sbin/mount.efs", line 1031, in bootstrap_logging
    raw_level = config.get(CONFIG_SECTION, 'logging_level')
  File "/lib64/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 607, in get
    raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'mount'
  Warning  FailedMount  110s (x2 over 4m4s)  kubelet, ip-192-168-42-94.eu-central-1.compute.internal  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[persistent-storage], unattached volumes=[persistent-storage default-token-d47s9]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

To me the error looks like it may not be related to my configuration, however as I expect AWS's example deployments to work, I doubt that. I'm neither familiar with python's ConfigParser nor with EFS, so I can only guess what that error really means. Thanks alot for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faced a similar problem.

Fixed by update efs-csi-node daemonset from `amazon/aws-efs-csi-driver:v0.3.0` image to `amazon/aws-efs-csi-driver:latest`

Comment: did you use `kubectl apply -k "github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/deploy/kubernetes/overlays/stable/?ref=master"` or `kubectl apply -k "github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/deploy/kubernetes/overlays/dev/?ref=master"` to install EFS into your cluster?

Answer (score 3):

This bug here seems to have already been fixed. So now it works fine if you install it in the following way.

```
kubectl apply -k "github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/deploy/kubernetes/overlays/stable?ref=master"
```

Settings that are incompatible with v0.3.0 images have been reverted by the following PR It seems.
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/pull/196